# Magento 2 Maximum error count has been reached or system error is occurred

Tags: image, csv, import, magento2

i try to import images product in magento 2 with csv file. I use import options in magento admin (System > Data Transfer > Import) but i get this error.[image]

My csv file have this columns

sku,product_type,attribute_set_code,name,price,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,additional_images

thanks

Hi, i find error in csv field but now i got permissions error

[image]

i use sudo chmod 777 -R va/import/images/ but doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure that you are uploading a CSV file? Maybe it is gzipped or something?

Comment: @MichałBiarda si estoy usando un archivo csv

Answer (score 0):

Did you find something in the logs?

Also, what if you try the import without images? (Just for testing, to be sure if the data or the files are the problems)